# How to cancel the jump function of cscope?

Tags: cscope

When I installed the cscope and the ctags, they share the same ctrl+] command, how can I cancel the jump fuction of cscope, retain only one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:set nocscopetag` should force vim to only search tag files on ctrl-].

`:set cscopetagorder=1` will make vim search tags files before cscope databases, but it will still fall back to cscope if it can't find the entry in the tags files.

Comment: Thank you ! I have one more question. When I open a C file, how to automatically load cscope.out database in the parent directory or multiple parent directory ?